# Laravel sales report table with multiple headers and rows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table Seller, Products, Invoice, and invoice_product. I want to create a daily sales report  with the seller name as a row header and products as a column like this

|  | Seller A | Seller B | Seller C | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Product 1** | 2 | 1 | 3 | 6 |
| **Product 2** | 1 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| **Product 3** | 5 | 2 | 1 | 8 |

What I want is the number of products sold by each seller, and if there isn't any product_id available in invoice_product for any seller than there should by zero. I am unable to come with up any solution.

**Seller Table**

- id
- seller_name

**Invoice Table**

- id
- seller_id
- total

**product table**

- id
- name

**invoice_product table**

- id
- invoice_id
- product_id
- qty
- amount

I tried

```php
$sales = Invoice::select(
        'seller_id',
        'invoice_product.product_id',
        DB::raw('SUM(invoice_product.qty) as qty')
    )
    ->groupBy('invoice_product.product_id', 'seller_id')
    ->join('invoice_product', 'invoice.id', '=', 'invoice_product.invoice_id')
    ->whereIn('seller_id', [1, 2])
    ->whereIn('invoice_product.product_id', [1, 2, 3])
    ->get();
```

Does anyone have a clue on how to obtain the desire result ?

Comment: what is invoice and invoice_product tables. What do you store in it, Where you store details of sold products?

Comment: @RioSant invoice table has a key seller_id which is a foreign key associated with the seller table. The details of the sold products are stored in invoice_products table

Comment: What result you are getting.  My guess is try using left Join

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you, utilizing Seller model instead of Invoice
and use package staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep.

```
// 1st query produce 2 sellers
$sellers = Seller::whereIn('id', [1, 2])->get()->keyBy('id'); 

// 2nd query product 3 products
$products = Product::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get()->keyBy('id'); 

        foreach ($sellers as $seller_id => $seller) {
            // run multiple queries depend on how many sellers do you have
            $data = Seller::query()
                ->find($seller_id)
                ->products()
                ->groupBy('product_id')
                ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(qty), 0) AS qty, product_id')
                ->pluck('qty', 'product_id');

            foreach ($products as $id => $product) 
            {
                var_dump('seller ' . $seller_id . ' | product ' . $product->id . ' | qty ' . (isset($data[$id]) ? $data[$id] : 0));
            }

            // counting total of products sold by each sellers
            var_dump('total ' . array_sum($data->toArray()));
        }
```

and this is relation inside Seller model

```
public function products()
{
return $this->hasManyDeep(
                Product::class,
                [Invoice::class, 'invoice_products']
            )
            ->withPivot(
                'invoice_products', 
                ['qty', 'amount']
            )
            ->groupBy('products.id');
}
```

This solution do require multiple queries to be run, depend on how many sellers do you have.